# AngularJS application loader

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a loader, and after the partial has rendered, I want to fade away the loader and display my application.

I have created the loader like so:

```
app.directive(
    "mAppLoading",
    function ($animate) {
        return ({
            link: link,
            restrict: "C"
        });
        function link(scope, element, attributes) {

            // NOTE: Am using .eq(1) so that we don't animate the Style block.
            $animate.enabled(true);
            scope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function () {
                if (!!element) {
                    $animate.leave(element.children().eq(1)).then(
                            // Remove the root directive element.
                            element.remove();
                            // Clear the closed-over variable references.
                            scope = element = attributes = null;
                        }
                    );
                }
            });

        }
    }
);
```

This code above will remove the loader and the page will show up, but at the wrong time. The page is still not loaded. Is there an event that I can use when the partial is done rendering inside `<div ui-view></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `$viewContentLoaded` event which you should use to determine if the content is loaded successfully.

```
scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
...
```

[Here](https://azizsaboor.wordpress.com/tag/viewcontentloading/) is a tutorial on this